# How to use music discord bot by my own bot

Tags: discord.js

I use my bot to join voice channel and type in chat list of commands for other bot - Groovy. But Groovy ignore my bot. When i try type command myself he work correct.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, developers add a condition to ignore the commands of other bots. Therefore, in your case, it is not possible to implement such functionality.